Windows 10 random freezes
Couple of months back my system started freezing up randomly. When it happens PC is completely frozen and requires cold reboot. No errors or abnormal artifacts appear on the screen.

Specs
CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 2700X
32Gb RAM
Video: Radeon RX 580
Windows 10 Home
System drive: Samsung 970 EVO

Anecdotally, it appears to be related to using Chrome browser, but I can't confirm it 100% due to random nature of the issue. Sometimes it freezes right away when starting up Chrome after reboot caused by the previous freeze.
Event Viewer doesn't show any errors prior to boot up.
Samsung Magician shows all good for the SSD.
MemTest86 shows all good for the RAM.
It's not a BSOD so no memory dump generated.
Freeze behavior appears to be similar to overheating, but I used Open Hardware Monitor to confirm that CPU, video card and motherboard temps appear to be within normal range (high 50C - low 60C when gaming, otherwise much lower).
I've tried clean reinstall of the video driver, Chrome data purge and finally "Reset this PC" Windows reinstall. I'm not even sure how to diagnose the cause at this point.

Update:
Switching to Firefox has stopped the freezes, so it appears Chrome was the culprit after all. Unclear why. Turning off the hardware acceleration in Chrome didn't help.
The question remains open as there a workaround but no solution.

If you have any reason to believe it's Chrome, try another browser for a while, such as Firefox (https://stackdiary.com/web-browsers-not-based-on-chromium/) to confirm.

Try : Click the Chrome three dots icon, select Settings > System and disable "Use graphics acceleration when available.". Restart Chrome.

@harrymc I've made that change. now we wait...

@DrMoishePippik I'll try that next after graphics acceleration, thanks.

Disabling hardware acceleration in Chrome didn't help. I've been using Firefox for two days now, and so far no freezes. I'll wait couple days more before declaring Chrome to be the culprit.
